# Views PHP filter criteria not working

Tags: 7, views

Why would this not work as a Views PHP filter criteria?

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2)) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $a1 = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');
  $a2 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('-2 months',strtotime($a1)));  
  $a3 = format_date($row->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');

  $b1 = new DateTime($a1);
  $b2 = new DateTime($a2);
  $b3 = new DateTime($a3);

  if ($b3 < $b2) {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

The code should remove rows that are older than the current node except it doesn't?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will remove the rows, when you return `FALSE`:

```
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2)) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  $a1 = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');
  $a2 = date('m/d/Y',strtotime('-2 months',strtotime($a1)));  
  $a3 = format_date($row->created, 'custom', 'm/d/Y');

  $b1 = new DateTime($a1);
  $b2 = new DateTime($a2);
  $b3 = new DateTime($a3);

  if ($b3 >= $b2 && $b3 <= $b1) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just swapped TRUE/FALSE since TRUE hides rows but as per your answer you do need the else statement